# Ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith' при поиске файлов с расширением

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
mypath = ("Y:/DIR"),("R:/")

filelist = []

for i in mypath:
    k = listdir(i)
    if k.endswith(".dwg") == True: filelist.append(k)
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Что вы в итоге хотите получить?

Comment: мне нужно получить из 2х списков с файлами, только названия файлов с расширением DWG

Answer (score 2):

Функция [`listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) возвращает список файлов (название функции как бы намекает). У списка нет метода `.endswith()`, это метод строки а не списка. Чтобы отобрать файлы с нужным расширением, нужно пройтись по списку, и уже из него отобрать нужные файлы. Т.е. нужен еще один вложенный цикл:

```
from os import listdir

mypath = ("Y:/DIR", "R:/")

filelist = []

for p in mypath:
    for filename in listdir(p):
         if filename.endswith(".dwg"):
             filelist.append(filename)
```

Или так:

```
from os import listdir

mypath = ("Y:/DIR", "R:/")

filelist = []

for p in mypath:
    filelist += [fname for fname in listdir(p) if filename.endswith(".dwg")]
```

Я бы еще по мере обхода файлов добавлял к именам файлов пути, иначе как потом разобраться, где первоначально лежал каждый файл:

```
from os import listdir, path

mypath = ("Y:/DIR", "R:/")

filelist = []

for p in mypath:
    filelist += [path.join(p, fname) for fname in listdir(p) if filename.endswith(".dwg")]
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)) буду разбираться)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти в заданных путях, файлы с указанным расширением:

```
from pathlib import Path

files = [p for dir in (r"Y:\DIR", "R:\\") for p in Path(dir).glob('*.dwg')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for folder in ['.idea', os.getcwd(), ]:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if ext == '.xml':
                full_name = os.path.join(folder, file)
                print(ext, full_name)
        break  # none recursive

print('os.walk / os.listdir')

for folder in ['.idea', os.getcwd(), ]:
    for ff in os.listdir(folder):
        full_name = os.path.join(folder, ff)
        if os.path.isfile(full_name):
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(ff)
            if ext == '.xml':
                print(ext, full_name)
```